# Change remote .config files

Tags: c#, winforms, configuration, config, remote-access

I have 2 servers called Web1 and Web2. Web2 runs a couple of services that use .config files. Web1 has a program that monitors if those services are running or not.

Now I also want to be able to change the .config files of the services from the app running on Web1. So I need a way to access those .config files.

I've already tried the ConfigurationManager, but either i'm doing something wrong or it's just not possible.

Here's what I've got:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ConfigurationFileMap fm = new ConfigurationFileMap(@"\\Web2\customer\CustomerNode.exe.config");
            Configuration conf = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(fm);
            conf.AppSettings.Settings["test"].Value = "blah";
            conf.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error " + err);
        }
    }
```

This gives me a Null exception, but I can't figure out why. Any help you could give me would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

using GlobalConfiguration you should be able to load new configuration, of course you should load or reset or restart your application. I have already done that to web services, after loading new configuration, i apply another method to reset application, and new config is valid then.
I guess things should be similar to application.